# Why is this limit equal to zero and not DNE

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The limit: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{2}{\sin x} $$

I know that 2 is just a constant and can be factored out of the limit, but the sine function oscillate between -1 and 1. Why does this oscillating function not result in DNE?

Comment: you are right, this limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorrry I don't know what  DNE is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the sequential characterization of limits we know that

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\ell\iff \forall \ (x_n)\to a,\ f(x_n)\to \ell$$

Now take $x_n=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$ so we have $x_n\to\infty$ and $\sin(x_n)=(-1)^n$ hasn't a limit.

Comment: Could you start explaining from $\left(x_n\right) \to a$?

Comment: That means: forall sequence $(x_n)$ convergent to $a$ the sequence $(f(x_n))$ is convergent to $\ell$.

Comment: Is $x_n = \frac{\left(2n+1\right)\pi}{2}$ an alternative form of $\sin x$?

Comment: No $(x_n)$ is a sequence convergent to $\infty$ but $(\sin(x_n))$ hasn't a limit so by the charecterization of the limit by sequences the function $x\mapsto\sin x$ hasn't also a limit at $\infty$

Comment: Follow up question, the limit or function has holes or jumps at $n\pi$?

Comment: We have $\sin(n\pi)=0$ and the function $\sin$ change signs at this point so $\lim_{x\to n\pi}f(x)=\pm\infty$